# How do I set the default editor for ghci for the :edit command on MacOS?

Tags: haskell, ghci

I installed GHC using `brew install ghc`. After opening an interactive session using `ghci`, the default :edit command is `code`. I am trying to change it to `subl`. I can do this by `:set editor subl`. After doing this, :edit correctly uses sublime text 3 to open files. However, if I close the session via `:quit` and reopen it, the :edit command is back to using `code` as its command.

Is there a way to change these settings "globally" I suppose?

Comment: GHCi has a [configuration file](http://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.4.1/docs/html/users_guide/ghci-dot-files.html) that you can use to automatically run commands on start.

Comment: Aha! I was looking for such a thing but my system didn't have one, so I created the file and added :set editor subl to it. Worked like a charm! Feel free to post your comment as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks!